# Applying for New Zealand student visa from Poland as an international student with third party nationality

Tags: study, paperwork, new-zealand

I am inside Poland with student visa type D national (I am not Polish). It was expired 4 months ago and I am living legally since they stamped my passport that I applied for rp.

Unfortunately, Poland issues rp very late sometimes two years. Now, I want to apply for the New Zealand student visa. I know that the application is all online and we are not going to anywhere to stick any visa in our passport. They will issue our visa as barcode.

However, I want to know whether I need to have rp card to apply or documents that show I am legally live here is enough? As I mentioned they just stamp our passport and I have address registered and bank account.

**I know still the visa is issued for the people with ITA code but I want to know from now on.**

Comment: Is "rp" Residence Permit?

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: This site is for short term travel, like vacations. We have another site for living, working and studying abroad called [expatriates.se]. This would be better there.

Comment: AFAIK temporary visa applications from outside New Zealand or a quarantine-free travel zone are currently suspended. The institution where you want to study may be able to answer your question.

Comment: MY QUESTION IS NOT ABOUT NOW CLOSED OR SO. My question is general!!